# How to enable multiple element with checkbox

Tags: javascript

I've experienced some code of enable/disable multiple html element by javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function enableDisable(bEnable, text_no1, text_no2, opt_no1, opt_no2){
        document.getElementById(text_no1).disabled = !bEnable
        document.getElementById(text_no2).disabled = !bEnable
        document.getElementById(opt_no1).disabled = !bEnable
        document.getElementById(opt_no2).disabled = !bEnable
    }
</script>
<label for="toggler"><input type="checkbox" id="toggler" autocomplete="off"
 checked="false" 
 onclick="enableDisable(this.checked, 'text_no1','text_no2','opt_no1','opt_no2')";>
&nbsp;Toggler</label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="text_no1"><br>
<input type="text" name="text_no1"><br>
<select name="opt_no1">
  <option>1</option>
</select>
<select name="opt_no2">
  <option>1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What question are you asking with this code? What's the problem you're having? Do you have a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) we could see?

Comment: I shared the code. I didn't ask!

Answer (score 0):

I'll guess that your issue is that "it doesn't work", that is, that the elements aren't disabled. That is partly because you are using `getElementById` to access elements that don't have an ID attribute (though likely it works in IE since it thinks IDs and names are the same thing).

You can either change the name attributes to ID attributes (since you aren't using a form that shouldn't be an issue), or keep the names and put the controls in a form, then access them as named properties of the form.

#### Edit

There are a couple of errors and omissions in your code:

1. The *checked* attribute does not have a value, it's a boolean attribute whose presence indicates "true" and absence is "false", so `…checked="false"…` is true and checks the checkbox.
2. There are two inputs with a name of *text_no1*
3. It seems checking the checkbox should enable the controls, the label should indicate that.
4. Using a form makes life easier to access form controls

Some working code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function enableDisable(el) {
      var f = el.form;
      var bEnable = el.checked;

      if (!f) return; // Stop if form not found

      for (var i=1, iLen=arguments.length; i<iLen; i++) {
        f[arguments[i]].disabled = !bEnable;
      }
    }
</script>

<form>
  <label for="toggler">
    <input type="checkbox" id="tggler" name="toggler" autocomplete="off" checked
     onclick="enableDisable(this, 'text_no1','text_no2','opt_no1','opt_no2')";>
     Controls enabled</label>
  <br>
  <input name="text_no1"><br>
  <input name="text_no2"><br>
  <select name="opt_no1">
    <option>1
  </select><br>
  <select name="opt_no2">
    <option>2
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: It seems to do nothing with the script. I still use it and it works fine. Thanks anyway for your suggestion.

Comment: It "works fine" only by accident, see example above. It also shows how to include any number of controls to enable or disable when the checkbox is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple script of what you are trying to achieve.

*(Tested in Chrome 21, Firefox 14, Internet Explorer 9)*

**The JavaScript**

```
function Switch() {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("Switch")

    var val = checkbox.checked

    document.getElementById("textbox").disabled = val

}
```

**The HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Switch" onChange="Switch()" />Disable/Enable
<br />
<input type="text" id="textbox"/>
```

**Live Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/jHVNE/1/

Comment: what if there're more element than textbox? Can I list other lines by the ID and make them switch up? For example I put document.getElementById("textbox2").disabled = val
document.getElementById("select1").disabled = val and so on.

Comment: Yes as long as `element` is valid, you can add any number of elements you would like to switch enabled/disabled.